# Canon mf4770n printer install not working Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: drivers, printing, macbook, canon

Just installed 16.04, downloaded latest printer driver from Canon (Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V320_us_EN).  Unpacked it, and installed with GUI (last week, so can't recall how exactly).  Shows up under Settings-> Printers, but shown as idle.   Went to localhost:631/printers/ and it lists CanonMF4700:  Location:(my)MacBook-Pro.local  Make and Model: Remote Printer  Status:Idle.   When I double click on the printer (CanonMF4700) I get a new screen that says: "The address wasn't understood"

My pc is an Acer Revo one, wirelessly connected to my router.  THe printer is connected to the router via ethernet cable.  Printer works from my MacBook Pro.   I can ping the router and the Acer PC from the Canon printer (under it's network settings), so the wireless/ethernet connections are working.  Also, internet is working from the Acer pc.